# Validate form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a form submit button is clicked, a function to validate all the field is to be called. Nothing is to happen, however, if the validation fails.

I am using `mailto:` as my action, does this make a difference?
I would like to get clarification on two things:

1. Is this the correct way to call a function when clicking the submit button?

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#contactForm').submit(function(){
           checkMail();
       });
   });
   ```
2. Can I still validate the fields even though I'm using `mailto:`?

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function checkEmail(){
    var email = document.contact.email.value;

    if(email == "") {
        document.getElemtById("email_error").innerHTML = "No Email Address";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = ""
        return true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="contact" action="mailto:exampleemail@hotmail.com" method="post">
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
    </li>
    <span id="email_error"></span>
```

Further, I don't get an error message on clicking submit.

Comment: You need to provide more HTML, namely, the form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need the event handler to `return false` in case the validation failed. This will prevent the action from being executed, i.e. the mail program from being launched.

> we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object **or by returning false from our handler**.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Modify it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(){
        return validate();
    });
});
```

Of course, this implies that the `validate()` function needs to actually return `false` in case the validation fails, **and** `true` *otherwise*.

**Further** you are missing `id="contactForm"` on your `<form>` tag.

Also, you need to grab the email value correctly:

```
var email = $("#email").val();
```

There's another mistake: You misspelled `getElementById()`. Here's a corrected version:

```
function checkEmail() {
    var email = $("#email").val();

    if (email == "") {
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "No Email Address";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = ""
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, using all jQuery:

```
function checkEmail() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var $error = $("#email_error");
    if (email == "") {
        $error.html("No Email Address");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $error.html("");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, so returning the function (return validate();) prevents the default action? no need for return false then?

Comment: @Richlewis I'm assuming the `validate()` function returns false when the validation fails. It then *acts as* `return false`. Edit: Clarified.

Comment: something still not working, im going to edit my post slightly, would you mind taking a look please?

Comment: apologies, little bit of confusion this end. Its my understanding (which is wrong) that $('#contactForm').submit(function() selects this element input id="contactForm" type="submit" value="submit">

Comment: ah now ive got it, thank you so much for your help, much cleaner way of getting the email value aswell, will keep that one in the memory bank, cant thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contactForm').submit(function(){
       if (!validate()) {
           return false; // Prevent the submit
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` to decide what boolean to return.

Comment: @phant0m It's the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

For validating the fields of your form, before sending it, you can use the jQuery's validation plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // some other code
            // maybe disabling submit button
            // then:
            $(form).submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Check the online doc for more information and examples: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21